# AVAudio layer is not playing the sound in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, avaudioplayer

Hi in my application I am using `UILocalNotifications` and `AVAudiopPlayer` to play a song. When a notification comes I am trying to play a song when I select notification alert. Here is the code, I am getting the sound but `isplaying` property is setting as YES.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{ 
    MainViewController *main=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
    [main playSong:notification.soundName];    
}

-(void)playSong:(NSString *)songName
{
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:songName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    [_audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Make sure, sound file is available or songName not should be nil. OR check your device valume.

Comment: All are fine no issue in those things.

Comment: What is sound name ? may I know ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following code and then try it may be help you.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    MainViewController *main=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
    [main playSong:notification.soundName];
}

-(void)playSong:(NSString *)songName
{
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:songName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    [_audioPlayer setDelegate:self];

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&errorAudio];

    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: @Naresh
I have replaced just one line as following :-

Old Line:-  `_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];`

New Line :-  `_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&errorAudio];`

Comment: I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi no luck.:(. I try the same but no use.

Comment: have you replaced the line i gave you?

Comment: Yes.    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vashudha Ke Is Aachal Me" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    NSError *errorAudio;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&errorAudio];
    [_audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    
    if(!_audioPlayer.playing)
        [_audioPlayer play];

Comment: Put this in your code.
`[_audioPlayer setVolume: 1.0];`

Comment: It may be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi thx i will try. But here strange thing is i am calling the same method when ever i click a play button which i have in xib. That time its working fine.